# Should Access Keys Remain Underlined When Dialog is Reopened?

Tags: windows, delphi, user-interface

I am using Delphi XE7 and my question pertains to when accelerator keys (aka Access Keys) should be displayed. Specifically, I have noticed that if I display a secondary form (ie, not the main form) and press the Alt key, the accelerators are displayed (the expected behavior). If I then close and re-open the dialog, the accelerators are still displayed (without pressing Alt). Is that considered correct Windows 7 behavior? If this is not correct behavior, then what code (if any) could I add to the form's OnShow that would rehide the accelerators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The platform standard is that access keys are shown if the dialog was invoked by a keyboard action. Once the dialog is shown, if you press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key then the access keys are shown.

So, why are the access keys shown when you open the form for a second time? Well, if you are creating the form each time you show it, then you will get the platform standard behaviour outlined above. So I conclude that in between first and second showing of the form you are merely hiding it, rather than destroying it.

So, the simple way to get the behaviour that you desire is to destroy the form when it is closed, and create it when it shown. Don't use the global form variable that the IDE creates for you. Don't call `Application.CreateForm` in the .dpr file to create that global instance. Whenever you need to show the form, create it at that instance. When the form is closed, destroy that instance.

If you have to re-show an existing instance of a form, then send a `WM_CHANGEUISTATE` message to initialize the state. Pass `UIS_INITIALIZE or (UISF_HIDEACCEL shl 16)` as `wParam`. If can't test any of this but it will be along these lines. I think it's enough to send this to just the form's window handle. And I might have got the flags wrong. Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646342(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The explanation is helpful. At this point in the project it would be a considerable amount of work to change when/how forms are created, so the question remains -- is there code that could be added to Onshow that would rehide the accelerators?

Comment: I've added some more info. Hope it helps.

Comment: That works. In case you wish to make your answer more specific for posterity, the following works when placed in the form's Onshow:    SendMessage(Handle,WM_ChangeUIState,UIS_INITIALIZE or (UISF_HIDEACCEL shl 16),0);